# Displaying same result again and again in Javascript phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova

we are getting same results in the loop. Please if anyone can understand that where i am making mistake please let me know. Please see this screenshot to get an idea.

I try alert many places and seems like everything is going fine. But dont know why not getting the results. do "executeSql" do not work properly with multiple values in loop?

Or is there any mistake in select query? Please let me know why, this is creating such problem?

[image]

```
   var db;
    var shortName = 'WebSqlDB';
    var version = '1.0';
    var displayName = 'WebSqlDB';
    var maxSize = 65535;


window.onload =  function(){

        document.addEventListener("deviceready",init,false);
    }

 function init(){

            if (!window.openDatabase) {
              alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
              return;
            } 

            db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize); 

            db.transaction(function(tx){ 
            tx.executeSql( 'DROP TABLE post_details',nullHandler,nullHandler);    
            tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post_details(UserId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, post_title TEXT NOT NULL, post_date TEXT NOT NULL,post_comment TEXT NOT NULL,post_content TEXT NOT NULL, post_categories TEXT NOT NULL, post_image TEXT)',[],nullHandler,errorHandler);
                },errorHandler,successCallBack);


            if(checkConnection() != "No network connection"){
                $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.foduu.com/api/get_recent_posts/?callback=?',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);

                    var number_of_post = Object.keys(data.posts).length;

                    for(var i=0; i < number_of_post; i++){

                                        var ptitle = data.posts[i].title;
                                        var pdate = data.posts[i].date;
                                        var pccount = data.posts[i].comment_count;
                                        var pcontent = data.posts[i].content;
                                        var pcategories = data.posts[i].categories;
                                        var pimage = "my image";
                                        //alert(ptitle +","+ pdate +","+ pccount+","+ pcategories +","+ pimage);
                                        db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                                            transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO post_details(post_title,post_date,post_comment,post_content,post_categories,post_image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',[ptitle,pdate,pccount,"pcontent",pcategories,pimage],nullHandler,errorHandler);
                                        }); 
                    }


                    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM post_details;', [],
                          function(transaction, result) {
                            $.each(result.rows,function(index){
                                var row = result.rows.item(index);


                                var post_single="<li class='post'>" + 
                                "<a href='#' class='post_more'></a>" +
                                "<div class='post_right_reveal'>" +
                                "<h4><a href='#' onclick='swiperParent.swipeTo(4);'>"+ row['post_title'] +"</a></h4>" +
                                "</div>" +
                                "<div class='post_right_unreveal'>" +
                                "Posted in <a href='#'>blog category</a>" +
                                "<span class='post_comments'>25 Comments</span>" +
                                "<a href='#' class='post_readmore' onclick='swiperParent.swipeTo(4);'>read more</a>" +
                                "</div>" +

                                   "<div class='post_left'>" +
                                       "<span class='day'>7</span>" +
                                       "<span class='month'>feb</span>" +
                                   "</div>" +
                                  "</li>";
                                   $('#posts-all').append(post_single);
                                   $('#posts-all').trigger('create');


                            });

                        });
                    },errorHandler,nullHandler);   

                },
                error: function(data){
                        alert("Can Not Fetch data From server");

                    }


                });

            }
            else
                {
                    alert("No Internet Connection"); 
                }

    }

function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        return states[networkState];
    }

function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
   alert('Error: ' + error.message + ' code: ' + error.code);

}

function successCallBack() {
   alert("DEBUGGING: success");
}

function nullHandler(){};
```

And is there any way i can load my main.js file before all the other JS or CSS file?

i tried executing multiple executeSql it worked very fine. But still when i am using it in FOR loop its just keep giving me the same title again and again. If needed i can place the code on github for you to try.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem is solved, i was running FOR loop out side the `db.trasaction(..)` it should be run on `tx.excuteSql(...)` this solve my problem.

I am glad i found the solution by myself.  :)

Thank you!